# Creating multiple sign up forms for different types of customers?

Tags: forms

What is the easiest way to create multiple forms based on what a user chooses from a drop down?

These are my options:

Consumers

Professionals with a license

And Professionals with no license

Is this a JavaScript issue or something like PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using javascript. Something similar to this should suit your needs

```
/*jQuery to control display/enableing of form fields depending on option selected */
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            $('#1 ,#2 ,#3 ').hide(); //Hide All Fields

            /*Display/Enable selected option*/
            $("#Options").change(
                    function() {
                        var selected = $("#Options option:selected").val(); //Get Selected Value    
                        $('#1 ,#2 ,#3 ').hide(); //Hide Fields
                        $('#1 ,#2 ,#3 ').find('input, textarea, button, select').prop('disabled', true);//Disable All Fields


                        $('#' + selected).find('input, textarea, button, select').prop('disabled', false);//Enable Fields in Selected Div
                        $('#' + selected).show();// Show Selected Div 
                    });
        });
```

JSFiddle of it working http://jsfiddle.net/Dobby90/ycapq649/